# What is a good UX for a Single Select Dropdown with an All option?

Tags: website-design, forms, user-behavior

I saw [Should multi-select dropdown/box have an "all" option?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/43672/should-multi-select-dropdown-box-have-an-all-option) but it is different.

This is for a Web UX.

EDIT:

This is a form that generates a report. The user chooses from a list of "locations" to include in their report. The number of locations will differ for each user. Let's say there are between 5 and 25 locations.

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? What is the user trying to choose between? How many options are there?

Comment: @maxathousand - Please see edit.

Comment: The question you link to is also talking about the web, so I don't see how this is different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should multi-select dropdown/box have an "all" option?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/43672/should-multi-select-dropdown-box-have-an-all-option)

Comment: So, they can ONLY select a single location, or ALL locations? There's no possibility they'll want to select two locations?

Comment: @JonW - Yes, one or all. Not two.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey - It is different because that it asks about Multi Select Dropdown, which is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your users have a binary choice (single or all), then potentially an additional required choice.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjcgQa.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I'm not sure of your user's common workflow or use case, but you could consider defaulting the radio button selection to "Single Location". This would require user intervention regardless (i.e. actually select a location, or select "All Locations") so there's no risk of the user accidentally submitting with incorrect prepoulated data.